# how to apply SameSite?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cookies, samesite

I'm only coding in HTML, CSS, and javascript.
the console shows me this:

> A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://fontawesome.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is an [issue with the FontAwesome library itself](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/15643): I've seen it on my site despite not setting any cookies related to FA. It has been reported on their GitHub.

You shouldn't have anything to worry about - try clearing your cookies and making sure you're using an up to date version of FontAwesome.